# Convert string to custom struct Go

Tags: go

Hi I have written code to read data from MongoDB.

It worked but I don't know how to convert string result to my custom struct.

Here is my code

```
type UserSSO struct {
    Username      string `json:"username"`
    Password      string `json:"password"`
    Lastname      string `json:"lastname"`
    Useremail     string `json:"useremail"`
    Usertel       string `json:"usertel"`
    Userdate      string `json:"userdate"`
    Userstatus    string `json:"userstatus"`
    Userparentid  string `json:"userparentid"`
    Comid         string `json:"comid"`
    Comdepartment string `json:"comdepartment"`
    Usercode      string `json:"usercode"`
    Usertype      string `json:"usertype"`
}
func GetInfomationChildOfNode(node string) (err error, info string) {
   ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
   client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://casuser:Mellon@222.255.102.145:27017/users"))
   if err != nil {
       return err, ""
   }
   defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
   database := client.Database("users")
   users := database.Collection("users")
   matchStage := bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"username", node}}}}
   graphStage := bson.D{{"$graphLookup", bson.D{{"from", "users"}, {"startWith", "$username"}, {"connectFromField", "username"}, {"connectToField", "userparentid"}, {"as", "descendants"}}}}
   unWind := bson.D{{"$unwind", "$descendants"}}
   replaceRoot := bson.D{{"$replaceRoot", bson.D{{"newRoot", "$descendants"}}}}
   proJect := bson.D{{"$project", bson.D{{"descendants", 0}}}}
   showInfoCursor, err := users.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{matchStage, graphStage, unWind, replaceRoot, proJect})
   if err != nil {
       return err, ""
   }
   var showsWithInfo []bson.M
   if err = showInfoCursor.All(ctx, &showsWithInfo); err != nil {
       return err, ""
   }
   data, _ := json.Marshal(showsWithInfo)
   stringData := string(data)
   fmt.Println(stringData)
   return nil, stringData
}
```

And here is my string result output

```
[{"_id":"5ee0ac96653a000065005c03","comdepartment":"KHOA_DIEN","comid":"DHBK","lastname":"KHOA_DIEN","password":"123456","usercode":"DHBK_0002","userdate":"2020-05-05","useremail":"KHOA_DIEN@edu.com.vn","username":"KHOA_DIEN","userparentid":"DHBK","userstatus":"ACTIVE","usertel":"0907111002","usertype":"USER_COM"},{"_id":"5ee0ac96653a000065005c04","comdepartment":"KHOA_XD","comid":"DHBK","lastname":"KHOA_XD","password":"123456","usercode":"DHBK_0003","userdate":"2020-05-05","useremail":"KHOA_XD@edu.com.vn","username":"KHOA_XD","userparentid":"DHBK","userstatus":"DISABLE","usertel":"0907111003","usertype":"USER_COM"},{"_id":"5ee0ac96653a000065005c08","comdepartment":"KHOA_DIEN","comid":"DHBK","lastname":"BOMON_HETHONG","password":"123456","usercode":"DHBK_0007","userdate":"2020-05-05","useremail":"BOMON_HETHONG@edu.com.vn","username":"BOMON_HETHONG","userparentid":"KHOA_DIEN","userstatus":"ACTIVE","usertel":"0907111007","usertype":"USER_COM"},{"_id":"5ee0ac96653a000065005c09","comdepartment":"KHOA_XD","comid":"DHBK","lastname":"BOMON1_XD","password":"123456","usercode":"DHBK_0008","userdate":"2020-05-05","useremail":"BOMON1_XD@edu.com.vn","username":"BOMON1_XD","userparentid":"KHOA_XD","userstatus":"DISABLE","usertel":"0907111008","usertype":"USER_COM"},{"_id":"5ee0ac96653a000065005c0a","comdepartment":"KHOA_XD","comid":"DHBK","lastname":"BOMON2_XD","password":"123456","usercode":"DHBK_0009","userdate":"2020-05-05","useremail":"BOMON2_XD@edu.com.vn","username":"BOMON2_XD","userparentid":"KHOA_XD","userstatus":"DISABLE","usertel":"0907111009","usertype":"USER_COM"},{"_id":"5ee0ac96653a000065005c0b","comdepartment":"KHOA_XD","comid":"DHBK","lastname":"BOMON3_XD","password":"123456","usercode":"DHBK_0010","userdate":"2020-05-05","useremail":"BOMON3_XD@edu.com.vn","username":"BOMON3_XD","userparentid":"KHOA_XD","userstatus":"DISABLE","usertel":"0907111010","usertype":"USER_COM"},{"_id":"5ee0ac96653a000065005c05","comdepartment":"KHOA_CNTT","comid":"DHBK","lastname":"KHOA_CNTT","password":"123456","usercode":"DHBK_0004","userdate":"2020-05-05","useremail":"KHOA_CNTT@edu.com.vn","username":"KHOA_CNTT","userparentid":"DHBK","userstatus":"ACTIVE","usertel":"0907111004","usertype":"USER_COM"},{"_id":"5ee0ac96653a000065005c06","comdepartment":"KHOA_DIEN","comid":"DHBK","lastname":"BOMON_TUDONG","password":"123456","usercode":"DHBK_0005","userdate":"2020-05-05","useremail":"BOMON_TUDONG@edu.com.vn","username":"BOMON_TUDONG","userparentid":"KHOA_DIEN","userstatus":"ACTIVE","usertel":"0907111005","usertype":"USER_COM"}]
```

In addition, I used this code to convert bson.M to struct, but it fail

```
    var userSSO UserSSO
    bsonBytes, _ := bson.Marshal(showsWithInfo)
    bson.Unmarshal(bsonBytes, &userSSO)
    fmt.Println(userSSO)
```

Result is `{           }`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The result from mongo seems to be an array of objects, no? If so, you have to decode it as such, i.e. instead of unmarshaling into a struct, unmarshal into a slice of structs.

Comment: @mkopriva the result is string because I use this stringData := string(data). If I don't convert it to string, it is []primitive.M

Comment: by "array of objects" i meant the content of the string (`stringData`) or byte slice (`data`). i.e. a string like `"[{ ... }, { ... }]"` represents an array with two objects.

Comment: @mkopriva yes, That is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var userSSO UserSSO
    bsonBytes, _ := bson.Marshal(showsWithInfo)
    bson.Unmarshal(bsonBytes, &userSSO)
    fmt.Println(userSSO)
```

You are marshalling with bson and trying to unmarshal with json. Both are different formats and hence this will not work.

You can do something like this below to unmarshal a map[string]interface{} (which is bascically bson.M) into a struct

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

type data struct {
    StringField string `json:"stringField"`
    IntField    int    `json:"intField,string"`
}

func main() {
    i := []bson.M{
        {
            "stringField": "foo1",
            "intField":    "123",
        },
        {
            "stringField": "foo2",
            "intField":    "456",
        },
    }

    bs, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var o []data
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &o); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Out: ", o)
}
```

Notice the `intField,string`. You can read more about this [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)

Comment: Your "i variable" is primitive.M but my variable showsWithInfo is []primitive.M. How to fix this?

Comment: @nistelrooy41001662 I have updated the code to use a slice